# Why my regex move next line to end of replace value?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace empty lines with `/////////////////////////`
Now I use following regex for this:

```
Find What : ^\h*\R
Replace With : /////////////////////////
```

this working but it move next lines of empty lines to end of them.
for example If I use regex for following list:

```
37,816,487
Newhart
34,617,539
0001+1986

TheCosbyShow
60,387,652
FamilyTies
53,326,512
Cheers
47,334,416
Murder,SheWrote
```

I get following result:

```
37,816,487
Newhart
34,617,539
0001+1986
/////////////////////////TheCosbyShow
60,387,652
FamilyTies
53,326,512
Cheers
47,334,416
Murder,SheWrote
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just match end anchor `$` instead of `\R`:

```bash
^\h*$
```

and replace with: `/////////////////////////`

`\R` in your regex will match a line break, thus joining next line to the end of the previous line.

`$` is zero width assertion like `^` or `\b`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lcjc0E/1)